# how to fetch attachment using ItemOperation command with file reference in Active Sync

Tags: c#, download, synchronization

I am trying to get attachment from a mail in C# legacy code. I have taken Active Sync Sample code from MSDN and using for testing. I am not getting any clue for download attachment. MSDN says that below should be request xml but I am not getting any sample code for same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ItemOperations xmlns:airsyncbase="AirSyncBase"
xmlns="ItemOperations">
  <Fetch>
    <Store>Mailbox</Store>
       <airsyncbase:FileReference>7%3a1%3a0</airsyncbase:FileReference>
  </Fetch>
</ItemOperations>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is correct but you have to convert that xml in wbxml (WAP Binary XML), this project might help you: https://wbxml.codeplex.com/

The codepages for the translation are here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219143(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219143%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

It's not simple to implement, but it will works!